# jQuery on click if/else not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I'm trying to create a condition to go to the next stage of a process.

The user needs select either 'Abandon' or 'Continue' before hitting the 'Next' button.

If one or the other is selected, hitting next button goes to the next page. If not, an alert says "Have you checked Abandon or Continue?

This is what I've done looking at other codes but it is not working for me. Nothing of the jQuery works, not even the alert =S Can anyone help me?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page</title>
<link href="remote_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$('#next').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#abandon' || '#complete').attr('checked') === "checked") {
        window.open('remote-user-testing5.html');
    } else {
        alert("Have you checked Abandon or Complete?");
    }
    return false;
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <h1>Instruction window</h1>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Now you will be asked to carry out 3 tasks and provide feedback on your experience.</p>
            <p>To complete each task, you will need to navigate through a website.</p>
            <p>Task complete: When you feel you have completed a task tick 'Complete' and click 'Next' in this Instruction Window.</p>
            <p>Abandon task: If you are finding it difficult to complete a task, tick 'Abandon' and click 'Next' this Instruction Window.</p>
            <p>Please remember we are not testing you, we are evaluating and testing the website.</p>
            <p>When you are ready click 'Next' to find out your task scenario.</p>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="abandon" id="abandon">Abandon<br>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="complete" id="complete">Complete<br>
            <button id="next">Next</button>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AmitAgrawal check "complete" and click next and you'll see it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your script needs to be run when the DOM is ready, and your selector is invalid you have to use separate ones and use `.is(":checked")`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#next').on('click', function() {
       if ($('#abandon').is(":checked") || $('#complete').is(':checked') ) {
           window.open('remote-user-testing5.html');
       } else {
           alert("Have you checked Abandon or Complete?");
       }
       return false;
   });
});
```

You need the [`.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function as if the DOM is not fully ready it cannot see the elements in order to select them.

[`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) checks to see if the selected elements has the passed argument, in this case `:checked` tests the `checked` attribute

Answer (score 1):

**Try :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#next').on('click', function() {
          if($('#abandon').is(':checked') || $('#complete').is(':checked')) {
              window.open('remote-user-testing5.html');
           } else {
              alert("Have you checked Abandon or Complete?");
           }
           return false;
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if ($('#abandon' || '#complete').attr('checked') === "checked")`

try

```
if ($('#abandon').attr('checked') === "checked" || $('#complete').attr('checked') === 'checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#next').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#abandon, #complete').is(':checked')) {
        window.open('remote-user-testing5.html');
    } else {
        alert("Have you checked Abandon or Complete?");
    }
    return false;
});
```